# referring multiple parents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am finding help on how to model tree structure or hierarchy in mongodb; however I have a problem where parent has multiple children and child has multiple parents.

Eg., in e-commerce site catalog, a smart phone can appear in electronics, computers or communications. so, there are 3 parents for smart phone here.

How do I model my mongodb for catalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Electronics", "Computers" and "Communications" would not be "parents" in this case. They sound like categories. Normally you store categories/tags in a nested array; so your document would looks similarly to this:

```
{
    brand: "Microsoft",
    model: "Lumia 950 XL",
    categories: ["electronics", "computers", "communications"]
}
```

You can filter your products based on categories:

```
db.products.find({ categories: "electronics" }).
```

Just add an index on `categories` to aid performance.

Comment: Thank you Dmytro. Let me model my database this way and check if that works for querying. I didn't think this way. Thank you.

Comment: I got this concept, how do I do this using path?

Comment: @kathi Do you mean category hierarchy?

Comment: If I use categories as you suggested then, I can find that Microsoft is available in electronics, computers and communications; however, if I want to find electronics and see if Microsoft is listed in electronics then query will be expensive because I have to find Microsoft and then see categories for electronics. It is same as building tree structure using Parent property.

Comment: I am new to MongoDB and I read the post about advantages and disadvantages of design patterns -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891484/mongodb-children-and-parent-structure. In my case, if user goes to electronics, he has to find Microsoft listed; if he goes to computes, he has to find Microsoft listed. User traverses from top to bottom of the tree.

Comment: @kathi I am sorry if I am not understanding you correctly, but - is something unclear in my answer? If you consider it helpful, you can upvote it and mark as accepted. If you have a new question, please post is separately. If you have any questions in regards to my answer, I can try to clear things up... but then tell me what you need help with.

Comment: I tried your design concept. It did not help. Let me explain. here are my requirements:
1. When user clicks on electronics, application should show Microsoft
2. When user clicks on computers, application should show Microsoft
3. When user clicks on communications, application should show Microsoft
4.

Comment: Listing electronics, computers, communications as categories is the best way to do this then, I will follow that way.
sorry, I still do not have enough reputations to vote.

Comment: @kathi What you outlined can be easily done with the way I described in my answer. You can filter on categories like this: `db.products.find({ categories: "electronics "})`. Just add an index on `categories` to aid performance.

Comment: Thank you Dmytro for all your help.