# Schema design for products and folders that contain products

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema, mongodb-schema

I have two schemas for products and folders

```js
const ProductSchema = new Schema<TProductSchema>(
    {
        productName: String,
        vendor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vendor' },
        folder: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductFolder' },
    }
);
const ProductFolderSchema = new Schema<TProductFolderSchema>(
    {
        folderName: { type: String, required: true },
        parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductFolder' },
        children: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductFolder' }],
    }
);
```

I want the following functionality in my application:

When user selects a folder, all products whose `folder` is equal to selected folder `_id` and whose `folder` is direct or indirect children of selected folder should be returned.

Folders and Products are separate entities: user can create and delete folders independently of products and vice versa.

The problem with current schema is that it's hard to implement finding products whose `folder` is a child of selected folder.

I expect each folder to contain up to 100.000 products.

I was thinking if adding `products` field that would contain product's `_id`s to `ProductFolder` is a good idea.

What schema design would you recommend? Should I add `products` field or leave it as is and come up with a solution to find nested folders? Or maybe there's some other approach?

Comment: Would this answer be helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909539/5716745

Comment: Check out  MongoDB's docs for different ways of storing hierarchical tree structures: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When user selects a folder, all products whose folder is equal to
> selected folder _id and whose folder is direct or indirect children of
> selected folder should be returned.

Here is a way to implement this, for example the models are:

```
product: {
  _id: <ObjectId>,
  name: <string>,
  vendor: <number>,
}

folder: {
  _id: <ObjectId>,
  parent: <ObjectId>,
  child: [ <ObjectId>, <ObjectId>, ... ]
  products: [ <ObjectId>, <ObjectId>, ... ],
}
```

**Example data** (shows some fields with data for a sample querying):

*products:*

```
 [ 
   { _id: "p11" }, { _id: "p12" }, { _id: "p13" }, 
   { _id: "p14" }, { _id: "p15" }, { _id: "p16" }, 
   { _id: "p17" }, { _id: "p18" }, { _id: "p19" }, 
   { _id: "p20" }, { _id: "p21" }, { _id: "p90" }, 
   { _id: "p91" }, { _id: "p92" },
]
```

*folders:*

```
[
  { _id: 1, parent: "...", children: [ 2, 3 ], products: [ "p11", "p12" ] },
  { _id: 2, parent: "...", children: [], products: [ "p13" ] },
  { _id: 3, parent: "...", children: [ 4 ], products: [ "p20", "p21" ] },
  { _id: 4, parent: "...", children: [ 40 ], products: [ "p16", "p17" ] },
  { _id: 9, parent: "...", children: [ ], products: [ "p92" ] },
  { _id: 40, parent: "...", children: [ ], products: [ "p90", "p91" ] },
]
```

The query is to get all the products for the current folder and its sub folders recursively.  Assuming the selected folder is `{ _id: 1 }`, the aggregation query uses `$graphLookup` and all the resulting "products" are listed in the `all_products` array.

```
db.folders.aggregate( [
    { 
      $match: { _id: 1 } 
    }, 
    {
      $graphLookup: {
          from: "folders",
          startWith: "$children",
          connectFromField: "children",
          connectToField: "_id", 
          maxDepth: 99999,
          as: "hierarchy"
      }
    },
    { 
      $project: {
          all_products: {
              $reduce: { 
                  input: "$hierarchy", 
                  initialValue: "$products", 
                  in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this.products" ] } 
              }
          }
      }
    },
] )
```

**Example's output**:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "all_products" : [
                "p11",
                "p12",
                "p16",
                "p17",
                "p13",
                "p20",
                "p21",
                "p90",
                "p91"
        ]
}
```

**Note** the `$graphLookup`outputs data in no particular order. Further, you can use `$lookup` to fetch the product details from the `products` collection (this stage is not shown in the query). The query runs in `mongosh`.

With this design, modifying data may require changing data in both collections. For example, if you delete a product, the data needs to be deleted from both collections.

Comment: thanks for the input. So you think it's a good idea to store all products in corresponding property even when there will be like tens of thousands of products?

Comment: You can store 10,000 or 20,000 product ids in an array (and within a document) - as long as you know that the number is not continuously growing (it needs to be bounded). Note that a document can have a size of 16 MB.

Comment: one folder can contain up to 100k product ids