# When to store foreign keys as a list, and when to store them as a separate column in a table. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Hey while browsing the MongoDB [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) I came across 2 code snippets like this.

```
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   books: [123456789, 234567890, ...]
}

{
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English"
}
```

and

```
{
   _id: "oreilly",
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA"
}

{
   _id: 123456789,
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

The second approach is perfectly understandable and logical to me, and one I have used throughout my adventure with SQL databases. However, I don't understand the first snippet. Why would I keep the FK in the list located in the publisher's record, instead of using the second code snippet?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909539/21972629) answer explain? Ultimately it's about knowing your data and how it will be queried. MongoDB is flexible enough to do both.